# Using core affinity for Debian servers: isolate core to specific tasks?

Tags: debian, high-load, load-average

I currently have an 8-core web server that is running into load problems due to heavy amounts of image processing--Imagemagick and other associated software will often spike the server's load up to 50+.

My thought would be to isolate Imagemagick onto one or two cores and then let all other processes distribute themselves on all other cores. Is there a way to set a core to exclusively work certain jobs with `taskset` AND ensure that no other tasks are assigned to that core? Is this something better handled by `numactl`?

Comment: What are the actual effects of the 50+ load? Have you used `nice` to decrease priority of the heavy image processing?

Comment: +1 for nice. You could create an alias for whichever imagemagick command is being run which uses nice.